When looking from specific angles, I seem to be able to peek through clothes. (Or they seem slightly torn rather)
When I use the numbad buttons (1,3 or Ctrl 1,3), I am able to see very small openings on the clothing on some specific spots, these are only visible when looking from this specific angles.

It looks like this, and some are visible only on sculpt mode while others can only be seen while on object mode. This one appears only while in
Ctrl + 1 view.

This one can only be seen while in Ctrl + 3 view.

Hello and welcome. Do you have a question we can answer? Could you edit your post and rephrase it to read like an actual question, with a clear enquiry we can answer?

I would assume that what you are seeing is Z-Fighting. You say you are working on clothing, so you probably have a model of a body below the clothing; If the clothing object is too close to the body object, then during the rendering process, the GPU will not be able to determine whether to draw the clothing or the body in front. This results in this screen door-like effect.
The obvious solution here would be to take the inflate brush in sculpting mode and move the clothing away from the body where appropiate. Thus, no more model overlapping will happen. I can understand if you don't want to change the shape of the clothing though; Instead, you could also delete or hide/mask out the parts of the underlying body model which will be covered by clothes. This way no body can peek out through the clothing (especially useful later, if you want to pose the model), and you reduce the poly count of the entire scene, which is also a nice plus.
